# How do I analyze trial level variability from a dot probe (reaction time) task?

Tags: variability

I have collected data from a dot probe attention bias (reaction time) task. I've computed summary scores for each condition, however, some people suggest it's important to also look at trial level variability. The computations for trial level variability seem complex and I am not sure what program and how to run these analyses. For example, one calculation for variability divides the total trials into eight sequential bins. Next, traditional attention bias (discrepancy) scores are calculated for each bin. The SD of those attention bias scores are then calculated and divided by the mean reaction time to provide a score of within-session variability of attention bias. If anyone knows a program that would allow for this type of computation and any guidance in how to set it up, I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Hannah! Welcome to CV. It would be appreciated if you mention the relevant info from the said paper here in your very post.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance - I've made some changes that hopefully make it more clear!